# Spring + Hibernate auto discover annotated classes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hibernate needs you to map all your Entity classes in Hibernate.cfg.xml, but I don't want to list all of them. I just want to reference the package in which they are all contained. I've read that Spring allows your application to autodiscover all your annotated classes with a bean for AnnotationSessionFactoryBean, but I don't understand how and where I'm supposed to configure this. I do NOT have a persistence.xml file anywhere in my application ==> I'm using Hibernate (Session instead of EntityManager, etc).

Comment: You are correct, Spring provides an AnnotationSessionFactoryBean that can scan your classpath for annotated beans.  From reading your question, it would seem as though you're not familiar with how to configure Spring?  Are you currently not using Spring in your application?

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC with Controllers, that's about it.

Comment: My tip is to consider using JPA - it will give you access to Spring JPA Data, but you still will be able to use `@Entity` classes and hibernate class autoscanning (of course it's not real JPA because of hibernate specific class scan but IMHO it's one of the simplest  and powerful configurations) http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all clarify whether you're using JPA or Hibernate directly. 
If you don't have any persistence.xml it might be that you're not using JPA (I would recommend using it though, you'll still be using Hibernate underneath, but your code will be more standard and independent of Hibernate).

Spring does support auto scanning of entity classes through:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name" />
```

I know it works for JPA, not sure for Hibernate directly.

My working spring application config file snippet looks like this, which includes the Hibernate properties (thus eliminating the need of the file completely):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:persistenceUnitName="persistenceUnitName">  <!-- this comes from persistence.xml -->

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">username</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">password</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxSize">100</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minSize">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleTestPeriod">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning spring, I recommend using spring ROO to setup your project.  This will setup all the spring best practices.  You could then move you classes into a new spring roo project (if your project is not too big/complicated).